# How to get healthkit's steps whether enabled in iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I am handle an iOS app and use data from health kit. When I move to setting and disabled steps component, I want to check that status in my app. I tried authorizationStatus but result is alway `sharingDenied`. Please support me to check it.

Comment: post code also how you check that and how you use healthkit data

Answer (score 0):

If user disables steps from:
**Settings -> Privacy -> Health -> Your App -> disable Steps switch**

It means that the user is not allowing the app to access steps data which implies that sharing is denied.

This is why the `HKAuthorizationStatus` is sharingDenied.

You can read the details here -
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkauthorizationstatus?language=objc

Comment: thank for your reply. I just referred and the document remind that: _HealthKit does not tell you when the user denies your app permission to query data_